# Difference between business and financial and data analyst

Tags: data-mining, finance, market-basket-analysis

Can anyone please tell me whats the difference between

Business analyst
Financial analyst
Data analyst

And what should one need to learn in order to achieve either of these profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Business Analyst

A business analyst is one who understands the specific domain of the project *(ex. retail, merchandising to be specific, supply chain etc.)*. His/her role is to understand the business problem, analyze the current state and capture requirements using various tools like `surveys, interviews, group discussions` and then provide recommendations and create a Requirements document for sign off.

#### Business Analyst Skillset-

> Communication,  Analytical thinking, Domain Knowledge, Generic
> technical Knowledge, Problem solving skills,Decision solving skills,
> Managerial Skills,Negotiation and Persuasion Skills.

### Financial Analyst

Financial analysts use financial data to spot trends and extrapolate into the future, helping their employers and clients make the best investing decisions. Businesses rely on financial analysts to determine when it is an auspicious time to buy or sell specific securities and, in some cases, companies use reports put together by financial analysts to determine if the entire business should be sold.

#### Financial Analyst Skillset-

> Financial analysts should be great problem-solvers, excel at the use
> of logic and possess strong skills in quantitative analysis. In
> addition, successful financial analysts have an in-depth understanding
> of various financial markets and investment products.

### Data Analyst

A data analyst's role is one that works with lots of data to derive meaningful insights to either address business problems or discover hidden trends and patterns that can be leveraged to meet the business objectives.

#### Data Analyst Skillset-

> Data analyst also needs similar skills with some additional skills
> like to analyze data like SQL, DATA mining, OLAP, Reports etc.

**Note:** Strong people skills, leadership ability, and teamwork are beneficial for each type career.

For more info, you can visit these resources-

- [Career Advice: Financial Analyst Vs. Data Analyst](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/professionals/120315/career-advice-financial-analyst-vsdata-analyst.asp)
- [What is the difference between data analyst and business analyst?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-data-analyst-and-business-analyst)
- [The Differences Between a Business Analyst & a Data Analyst](http://work.chron.com/differences-between-business-analyst-data-analyst-17090.html)

Hope it helps, cheers! :)

Comment: You are very great abhishek bhai... You are always here for rescue

Comment: Thanks for your kind words man. I do try my best. Cheers! :)

Comment: But thanks... I am trying to search an entirely new career in data science so i am learning a lot these days... So this platform and your answers are very good motivators... Thanks again

Comment: Cool! DataScience is a fun, go with it. Kudos! :)

Comment: Thanks is there any way here to add friend or add circle our something like that

Comment: No man, there isn't anything like that. But it will be surely available on my community, once it's done!

Comment: ok then make sure to add me once you have any community

Comment: Sure, will invite you, man.